Why can NBA trigger sensitivity list of always block it is inside of but blocking statement doesn't?
I have read that event scheduling takes place after the blocking statement is executed in the active region; hence, the change in signal in the sensitivity list can be missed, but that is not the case for NBA.
always @(clk) #10 clk <= ~clk;

Above code generates a clk signal on giving a trigger with an initial block. The following only executes once.
always @(clk) #10 clk = ~clk;

Can anyone explain when does the sensitivity list picks up changes in it with regard to active, inactive and NBA region?

An event control @signal is a construct that is part of a procedural process. It waits for an event to happen. The process has to execute the construct first before the event happens. It is clearer if you rewrite your always block that shows the procedural flow better as follows
always 
 begin
    @(clk)
    #10
    clk = ! clk;
 end

The problem with using the blocking assignment is the process updates the value of clk in the same active region before reaching the end of the begin/end, so the update to clk has already happened before executing the @(clk) event control in the next iteration of the always loop.
When using a nonblocking assignment, the loop returns to the next iteration of the always loop and executes the @(clk) in the active region before the update to clk` happens in the nonblocking region.
BTW, both forms you show require that some other process create an event on clk at some point away from time 0, otherwise you may never get into the loop.
A better, more efficient way to model a clock is without any event controls.
always #10 clk = ! clk;

If you need to phase shift your clock, use a forever loop instead of always
initial begin
  clk = 0;
  #3
    forever #10 clk = ! clk;
  end


Thank you for the explanation. Can you elaborate on how this compares to using a nba and why the event trigger picks up change in the signal ?

@VedanShet, I've elaborated my answer
